# Squeezing (8750, 4, 35) np array to (35000, 35)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array with the shape of (8750, 4, 35) which I'm trying to squeeze to (35000, 35). I tried with `np.squeeze`:

```
a = np.array(pred_f)
np.squeeze(a).shape
```

but this still produces (8750, 4, 35) and changing the axis parameter causes an error:

```
ValueError: cannot select an axis to squeeze out which has size not equal to one
```

Does anyone have any clue on how can I do this?

Comment: you want reshape, not squeeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((8750, 4, 35))
a = np.reshape(a,(-1,35))
print(a.shape) #(35000,35)
```

Like Dr.Snoopy mentioned, `reshape` is what you are looking for. It would look something like this.